# how numpy operator * and dot works

Tags: python, numpy

```
x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = x[:, np.newaxis]
print(x*y)

output:
[[1 2 3]
 [2 4 6]
 [3 6 9]]
```

My question on the above is that I do understand that * is element-wise multiplication. x shape (3,)
and y shape is (3,1). I am not getting how output is calculated. From my testing, the output is not
changing if we use x * y or y * x. I think here some kind of broadcast happens,  Kindly explain
how this works.

Another question is on following

```
vector_a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]) 
b = [1,2, 3]
c = np.dot(vector_a, b)

here c value: [14 32] and shape is (2,).
```

I do understand dot is matrix multiplication, here a shape is (2,3) and b shape is (3,). Here
again, broadcast happens I think and output shape should be (2,1), but output shape is shown as (2,)
How this is calculated? Here c = np.dot(b, vector_a) is thrown as error

shapes (3,) and (2,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 0) != 2 (dim 0)

Here why broadcasting is not applied. that (3,) should become (3,2) and output should be of shape (3,3)

Kindly explain.

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: A great place to start would be: [Numpy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and this: [Array Broadcasting in Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/theory.broadcasting.html#array-broadcasting-in-numpy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, the broadcasting is:

```
 (3,) * (3,1) => (1,3) * (3,1) => (3,3)
```

The two rules are:

```
1) add leading dimensions as needed to even the number
2) adjust all size 1 dimensions to match the other
```

As for `dot`, no broadcasting; read the docs for details.  If both are 2d, the rules are simple - `np.dot(A,B)`, last of A matches 2nd to the last of B, and is eliminated by summing.

But 1d arrays get special handling, that is well documented.

```
(2,3) and (3,) -> the 3's match and sum, leaving the (2,)

np.dot(A,B) 
np.sum(A*B[None,:], axis=1)
(2,3) * (1,3) => (2,3) sum on dim 1) => (2,)
```

`np.matmul/@` does describe it's handling of 1d arrays in terms of expanding, and squeezing.

```
np.matmul(A,b)
(2,3) @ (3,) => (2,3) @ (3,1) => (2,1) => (2,)
```

`np.dot` doesn't describe things in those terms, though the effect is the same.

Comment: Thanks for help. can you please elaborate sentence "2,3) and (3,) -> the 3's match and sum, leaving the (2,), and last of A matches 2nd to the last of B, and is eliminated by summing

Comment: Matrix multiplication is frequently described being sums of products.  A web search for "matrix multiplication by hand" yields lots of illustrations.  All that's special here is the handling of the 1d (3,) array.